# Is there anywhere i can get support with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Apparently not here.

Is there any forum, community or something where i can get help with JMeter?

I have installed JMeter for the first time today. I am trying to do a simple SOAP request. When i run a method the error:

"An error occurred when verifying security for the message"
shows in the Result tree.

Makes sense. In Soap UI (What i normally use) i have to give the following credentials in the request property:

```
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
Domain: empty
Authentication type: No authorization
WSS-Password Type: "PasswordText"
```

In SOAPUI this works. When i execute this method i get my results

So i tried in JMeter to add "HTTP Authorization Manager" with:

```
Base URL: Same url as i use in the test request
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
domain: empty
realm: empty
Mechanism: tried both options
```

When i run in again no change. It doesn't seem like JMeter even looks are the values in the HTTP Authorization manager. I tried to add it in the root of the Thread group and i tried to make it a child of the request

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: any feedback on answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch Http Request Implementation to HttpClient3.1 in all your requests or use Http Request Defaults and do it there only once.